# Possible exploit in phpmyadmin links http://dev.mysql.com/

Tags: phpmyadmin, token, exploit

I noticed when I execute query in phpMyAdmin it shows it on the screen as link.
When you click on that link it forward you to http://dev.mysql.com/ with the related query
Isn't that an exploit?

So they can get your token by saving your:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

I tried it with JS and I noticed it shows the last url

```
document.referrer 
"http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=www_&table=meeting_planner&target=tbl_sql.php&token=a24a6bfb214586e23954....."
```

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the token is the one [discussed here](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Security_Of_phpMyAdmin), then yes. It is a vulnerability (albeit a minor one).

It allows the anti-CSRF token to leak to a specific site (which has been selected by the authors of the software and is *probably* trustworthy).

You should be able to mitigate it by accessing PHPMyAdmin over HTTPS (which tends to block referer information when leaving for a different site).

---

CSRF defences work by having two copies of the token. One in a cookie (or session) and one in the form.

There is *generally* no need to defend against CSRF attacks for operations which only read data, and operations which write data should be POST forms, so the CSRF token should never appear in a URL.

phpMyAdmin is a bit of an odd duck in that a read operation can very easily be used to trigger a DOS attack on the server (since you can send SQL queries). These requests should probably use CSRF tokens, but since adding them will make the link unbookmarkable / sharable, the post might as well use POST here anyway.

Comment: No it should not be a cookie. That is very much the point of anti-CSRF tokens to not be a cookie which the browser may automatically send to a server without the attacker knowing the value.

Comment: @yankee — It wasn't clear which of the two copies of the token the one in the URL was. I've rewritten that part of the answer.

Comment: If i understand it correctly this token is usless without the cookie?

Comment: @talsibony — No, because if you can link the token to a user (which you can if you get it out of their referer) then you can craft a form which embeds that token and send their browser back to the original site to make whatever request you like (and their browser already has the cookie).

Comment: Wow so I really found an exploit!

Comment: Possibly. Note the first line of the answer. It's certainly something worth looking at to make a test case.

Answer (score 0):

Quentin's explanation was pretty good; I have nothing to add to that -- but this was fixed back in February with phpMyAdmin 4.2 (I just forgot to post this here until now).